# FDR adjusted p-value, nothing exceed 0.05

Tags: false-discovery-rate

I have a dataset that contains 8.2 million p-values. 
Here's the distribution of the negative log p-values; 
[image]

After I did the `p.adjust` with `BH` method in R, here's the distribution of the negative log FDR p-value. I don't have anything that's < 0.05 or even 0.4!!
[image]

Could anyone help me with the following, (1) is my FDR analysis correct? (2) what would be a better way to do multiple testing corrections for such a large dataset/.

Here's my code:

```
dat$fdr_adj_pval <- p.adjust(dat$p, method="BH", n = length(dat$p))
```

A little update:

I did the qvalue test

```
fdr_qvalue <- qvalue::qvalue(dat$fdr_adj_pval)
summary(fdr_qvalue)
```

and here's the results

```
Call:
qvalue::qvalue(p = dat$fdr_adj_pval)

pi0:    1   

Cumulative number of significant calls:

          <1e-04 <0.001 <0.01 <0.025 <0.05 <0.1      <1
p-value        0      0     0      0     0    0 8262594
q-value        0      0     0      0     0    0 8262594
local FDR      0      0     0      0     0    0       0
```

Comment: As written, not clear enough. FDR and FWER correction both seek to reduce the number of false positives, so the number of tests doesn't matter. If this is an actual analysis, consider that there may in fact be no associations or if they're there, you just don't have enough power.

Comment: Any other statistical methods to guide me through this? Thanks very much.